# Correct way to use get_or_create on model object

Tags: django, orm

I know how get or create work with the values like

```
Car.get_or_create(name="Canro", model=2012 ... .. many other fields)
```

but when I have adding or Updating the car object using django forms, how can I check if user have entered a car who is already in the db?

One way could be,

```
have_in_db = Car.objects(name=user_entered.name)
if have_in_db:
  have_in_db.model!=user_entered.model
  # many other fields.
```

i want to try somthing like that.

```
Car.get_or_create(**user_entered)
```

can i have anyway in django to do that?

Comment: You want to check, is there a car with same parameters, as in [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/), before saving a form?

Comment: Yes. if in my model, Car, is there any object with same params as entered by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this logic in my view's `form_valid` like so:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object, created = Car.objects.get_or_create(
        **form.cleaned_data
    )
    return super(CarCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

To put that in context, I have a complaints case management system that registers new complaints in stages. When someone wants to complain their details are stored in a `Complainant` model that creates a new complainant for someone's first complaint but doesn't for subsequent ones. They are then redirected to a `Case` model form along with their `id` value, which is automatically added as the `Case` object's foreign key to the `Complainant` object. That model form looks like this:

```
class ComplainantCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Complainant
    form_class = ComplainantForm
    login_url = "/login/"
    permission_required = "complaints.add_complainant"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object, created = Complainant.objects.get_or_create(
            **form.cleaned_data
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse(
                'select_case',
                args=[self.object.pk],
            )
        )
```

Comment: Does what actually was asked.

Answer (score -1):

Do it in form's `clean` method:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Car

class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car

    def clean(self):
        if self._meta.model.objects.filter(**self.cleaned_data).count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Car already exists')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asks. It returns an error where it already exists instead of fetching the object.

Comment: @cms_mgr if it is needed to update the object, then use UpdateView, not CreateView. If you'll mess the patterns, the code will be very hard to maintain and read

Comment: I agree but there are situations, such as the one set out in my answer, where you want to create something without knowing whether another object on which it relies exists already. `get_or_create` offers a better user experience in those situations than an error does.